# Toggle numa div ao lado (ou abaixo)

Tags: jquery, div, toggle

Eu estou precisando manipular uma `div` a partir do click em outra `div`.

Basicamente, uma está em cima da outra, quero clicar na de cima e assim a de baixo executa o evento `.toggled()`. Porém uma não pode estar dentro da outra.

HTML

```
<div id="titulo" class=" toggled " align="left">Histórico</div>
<br>
<div id="divTabela">
    <table id="tabelainfo" name="tabelainfo" class=" bordasimples ">
    <thead>
    <tr id="titulotabela">
        <th>Data</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr id="corpotabela">
        <td align="center">15/5/2014 </td></tr>
    <tr id="corpotabelaalt" align="center">
        <td align="center">16/5/2014 10:56:10</td></tr>
    <tr id="corpotabela">
        <td align="center">16/5/2014 11:00:28</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
<br><br></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$("*").on("click", ".toggled", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    console.log($(this));
    $(this).css({"color":"red","border":"2px solid red"});
    $(this).next("div").toggle();
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayconfsbrito/2kLpu/2/)</kbd>

O que vocês me sugerem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#elemento-de-clicar').click(function(){
    $('#elemento-alvo').slideToggle();
 });
```

Comment: Insira o .next() entre o seletor e o método slideToggle(), assim a sua resposta estará certinha, assim como o novo Fiddle onde inseri a correção a partir da sua sugestão: http://jsfiddle.net/mayconfsbrito/2kLpu/4/

Comment: Esqueci do .next(). Muito obrigado ai por apontar rs.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- HTML -->    
<p class="linkToggle">
   <strong><span>[+] </span>Detalhamento dos Pacotes de Serviços</strong>
</p>
<div class="lista forToggle">
    olá mundo!
</div>
<!-- HTML -->


<script>
       $('.linkToggle').click(function () {
             $(this).next(".forToggle").toggle('slow', function () { });
             var val = $(this).html();
             if (val.indexOf("[+]") > -1)
                  $(this).html(val.replace("[+]", "[-]"));
             else
                  $(this).html(val.replace("[-]", "[+]"));
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Recebe o click na classe ".linkToggle" e aplica a animação no próximo elemento com a classe ".forToggle".